# Construct 2 to Construct 3 Syntax

Tags: construct, construct-2, construct-3

I am trying to follow a tutorial but the tutorial is in construct 2 (https://www.construct.net/en/tutorials/multiplayer-tutorial-chat-room-591/chat-events-3?vic=12)

In Construct 2, you would use: self.text & newline & Function.Param(0)

However, in Construct 3 it is showing an error on the **Function.Param(0)** part.

How would I write this?

Answer (score 1):

In Construct 3 function, right click on the function name and add parameter as shown in image below. then you can use the parameter like how you use local variable
[image: 1]